# how to execute db script in oracle and output a log file

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Normally in DB2, if I want to execute a db script and output the execution result to a log file, I will do something as follow:

```
db2 -tvf x.sql > x.log
```

Hence, I can read the x.log to check whether my script is execute correctly or not.

How about Oracle db?

I know that the script is run as follow:

```
SQL>@x.sql
```

But how can I output the execution result like what I do in DB2?

Kindly advise.

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: Hi @FrancescoB. , I tried your way, but nothing is generate in filename.txt even the x.sql run successfully.

Comment: but filename.txt is being created, right? can you delete it and let the command recreate it?

Comment: I edited my solution. Basicaly I had to add "SPOOL OFF", which should force writing to the file.

Comment: Hi @FrancescoB. , will get back to you once I try on it. Currently on other project, probably will do it tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

Using [SPOOL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12043.htm)

```
SPOOL filename.txt
@x.sql
SPOOL OFF
```

> Stores query results in a file, or optionally sends the file to a printer

Other options you can use:

> CRE[ATE]
>
> Creates a new file with the name specified.
>
> REP[LACE]
>
> Replaces the contents of an existing file. If the file does not exist,
> REPLACE creates the file. This is the default behavior.
>
> APP[END]
>
> Adds the contents of the buffer to the end of the file you specify.
>
> OFF
>
> Stops spooling.
>
> OUT
>
> Stops spooling and sends the file to your computer's standard
> (default) printer. This option is not available on some operating
> systems.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a FAQ  , try using shell redirection with sqlplus:

```
sqlplus  your_connect_string_here  @x.sql  1>x.out 2>&1
```

Consider also using inside the script:  `set termout on`  and the `spool` command to further adjust the behaviour. Refer to the Oracle sqlplus documentation for all the details.